# How do I specifiy or override the file and path name for ftp publish location after a hudson build?

Tags: ftp, hudson

I am using hudson and the "Publish artifacts to FTP" option.  It makes up its own directory based on the date and time of the build.  I would like to override that with a fixed name/location.  How can I do that?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

What version of the [FTP Publisher plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/FTP-Publisher+Plugin) are you using? I just installed the `1.0` version on Hudson 1.361, and in that version I can control the path by selecting the `Flatten files` option in the job configuration. Timestamp directories can also be disabled (that was the default).

That would solve path control. For the filename control, there doesn't seem to be a way to rename the file. You will either have to create an artifact with the right name during the build, or use some other tool for the ftp upload.

**Edit**: For example, the [Post Build task](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task), that can run arbitrary shell commands based on the result of the build.

Comment: I'll check into that.  It looks like I have .9 of the ftp plugin on my build server.  hudson version 1.341